# Github not showing correct # of lines of code

Tags: git, github

I ran `git init` in an existing project and pushed the project to github. On graphs/contributors page, it says 1 line of code committed, when it should be more. What did I do wrong and how can I fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The page is cached and not generated in real time, in particular the contributors section. It may take a while before the cache expires and the value is calculated again from the repository.

Answer (score 0):

In my config I forgot to set up the author